# Plot multiple bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def plotbars(hists, bins, labels, filename):
    plt.figure()
    center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
    width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
    for hist in hists:
        plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
    plt.legend(labels)
    plt.savefig(filename)
```

If I plot histograms like this `plotbars([hist1, hist2], bins, ['hist1', 'hist2'], 'histo.png')`, this plots the histograms on top of each other. I want to the bars of the histogram to be adjacent. The bin width for each are equal.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `hists` is?

Comment: its the output of `np.histogram()`

Comment: It would be much easier for us if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean adjacent in the same figure? Then you have to shift your `center` to the right in each iteration. For instance to `center  = [c + offset for c in center]`, where `offset = bins[-1] - bins[0]`, in every iteration of your `for`-loop, or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using plt.hist instead of plt.bar.

```
hist1=[x for x in range(0,10)]*10
hist2= [x for x in range(0,10)]*2
plt.hist([hist1,hist2],bins = 10)
```

Yields this image:

[image]

Is this how you would like to see your graph?

Update:

x axis can be properly formatted using the following.

```
bin_list = [x for x in range(0,11) ]
plt.hist([hist1,hist2], bins=bin_list ,align='left')
```

Resulting in a proper spaced x axis. For some reason it appears bins must be set as a list for proper spacing of x values.

[image]

https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks

For further tweaking you can try to play around with plt.xticks().

Comment: Yes, I'd like a graph that looks like this. But how do I plot `x` axis properly?